# Need help implementing a Case Statement in OpenLayers for varying pin color based on location status

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers, I am trying to populate a world map of customer locations with pins that will vary in color based upon a certain status of that location. The status are numebred 0-4 and the first column in the referenced .CSV.

How can I change the color of the pin based on teh status?

```
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import {Stamen, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import WebGLPointsLayer from 'ol/layer/WebGLPoints';
const source = new VectorSource();
const client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open('GET', './data/FSI_Site_Data.csv');
client.onload = function () {
    const csv = client.responseText;
    const features = [];
    let prevIndex = csv.indexOf('\n') + 1; // scan past the header line
    let curIndex;
    while ((curIndex = csv.indexOf('\n', prevIndex)) != -1) {
        const line = csv.substr(prevIndex, curIndex - prevIndex).split(',');
        prevIndex = curIndex + 1;
        const coords = fromLonLat([parseFloat(line[4]), parseFloat(line[3])]);
        if (isNaN(coords[0]) || isNaN(coords[1])) {
            // guard against bad data
        continue;
    }
    features.push(
        new Feature({
            status: parseInt(line[0]) || 0,
            geometry: new Point(coords),
        })
        );
    }
    source.addFeatures(features);
};
client.send();

const Sites = new WebGLPointsLayer({
    source: source,
        style: {
            symbol: {
                symbolType: 'circle',
                size: 12,
                color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                opacity: .5,
            },
        },

});

new Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new Stamen({
        layer: 'toner',
      }),
    }),
    Sites,
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

I'm thinking a Case Statement will be the way to go but have been unable to figure out how and where to put it. This is my first run at Jave/JSON. My VBS/VBA ways are not helping me out one bit.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: `palette` would be simpler if it works with feature properties - the only example I can find is in a test https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/test/rendering/cases/webgl-palette/main.js  In your case something like 
`color: ['palette', ['get', 'status'], ['rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgb(0, 255, 0)', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)', 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', 'rgb(255, 0, 255)', 'rgb(0, 255, 255)']],`

Comment: `palette` seems to not woek inside a `symbol` declaration.  A slightly simpler alternative to `case` is `match`, for example
`color: ['match', ['get', 'status'], 0, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 1, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)', 2, 'rgb(0, 0, 255)', 3, 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', 4, 'rgb(255, 0, 255)', 'rgb(0, 255, 255)'],`

Comment: Thanks Mike! I have been trying to get pallette to work, no joy. Glad it's not just me. Will try the match out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Mike's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76291168/need-help-implementing-a-case-statement-in-openlayers-for-varying-pin-color-base/76308409#comment134549855_76291168) solved this:

> `palette` seems to not work inside a `symbol` declaration. A slightly simpler alternative to `case` is `match`, for example,
>
> ```
> color: ['match', ['get', 'status'], 0, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 1, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)', 2, 'rgb(0, 0, 255)', 3, 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', 4, 'rgb(255, 0, 255)', 'rgb(0, 255, 255)']
> ```